# making new line in JS

Tags: javascript, newline

Hi I have this JS code

```
  function myFunction() {
  var g;
```

> ```
> var d = new Date().getDay();
> switch (d) {
>     case 0:
>         g = "Today it's Sunday";
>         break;
>     case 1:
>         g = "Today it's Monday";
>         break;
>     case 2:
>         g = "Today it's Tuesday";
>         break;
>     case 3:
>         g = "Today it's Wednesday";
>         break;
>     case 4:
>         g = "Today it's Thursday";
>         break;
>     case 5:
>         g = "Today it's Friday";
>         break;
>     case 6:
>         g = "Today it's Saturday";
>         break;
>     default:
>         x = "Looking forward to the Weekend";
> }
>
>
> var y; //popup
>
> var name = prompt("Please enter your name", " (your name is here)");
>
> if (name != null) {
>     y = 'How are you today?';
>     document.getElementById("popup").innerHTML = y; //
> }
> var x = ""; //שעה
> var time = new Date().getHours();
> if (time < 12)  //תנאי
> {
>     x = "Have a beautiful morning " + name + '! ';
> }
> else if (time < 16) {
>     x = "Great noon! Enjoy this day " + name + '!';
> }
> else if (time < 19) {
>     x = "Great afternoon! Enjoy them " + name + '!';
> }
> else if (time < 23) {
>     x = "Good evening! have some fun and take some rest befor the day over" + name + '!';
> }
>
> document.getElementById("demo").innerText = x + "<br/>" + g; 
> }
> ```

why whan I put the br tag in its just writs the br tag on the screen and there is now break between the line?
I alsow tried to put the "\n" and it doesnt work too. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the `<br/>` tag become an element, you'd need to set the `innerHTML` instead of `innerText`.

The `\n` approach would have also worked. Only, whitespaces don't appear in the layout usually. If you set the CSS style of the `#demo` element to `white-space:pre-wrap;`, the linebreak will show up.

Comment: thanks.
so why whan I put this line it isn't work? document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x +/n +g;

Comment: You want `…innerText = x + "\n" + g;` (innerHTML should work as well, but is not needed here)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML) rather than [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent). However beware of different kinds of security attacks and [sanitize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) the user-provided text (i.e. `name`).

Comment: It works...  but for next time: how can I put the "\n" (new line" in this script? what what is the different between innerText to innerHTML?

Comment: Setting `innerText` pretty much sets the sanitized text content of an element. I.e. if you write `element.innerText = "<script>"`, you will see exactly `<script>` inside the element (its `innerText` being `&lt;script&gt;` or something similar), while setting `innerHTML` to the same value will give you a broken DOM tree (non-closed `<script>` element). So, you cannot have a plain newline set in the `innerText` unless the element preserves formatting (e.g. `<pre>`). Then a pure `"\n"` will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

you are setting the innerText which will only set the Text of the Element.
Try :

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x + "<br/>" + g;
```

Comment: what is the different between innerText to innerHTML?

Comment: innerText will set only the Text (handling the string you are writing to the element just a text and will replace <br/> with smthg like &gt;br/&gt;) in the Element you define.
innerHTML will handle the string you are writing to the Element as HTML and not just a normal Text.

Comment: so, why whan I put this line it isn't work? document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x+/n +g;

Comment: x+/n+g; ??? is not a valid HTML code !!! 
When setting innerHTML you need to set html code