# Escape sequences in JavaScript not working?

Tags: javascript

It seems that escape sequences in JavaScript don't work? I'm writing in HTML 5 and am a fairly newbie. Single quote, double quote, and backslash DO work. But newline \n, backspace \b, carriage return \r, and tab \t don't work. Can anyone give me an idea why it's not? or a workaround?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hey bob!, \'You is da bomb!");
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [making new line in JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12422201/making-new-line-in-js)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But newline \n, backspace \b, carriage return \r, and tab \t don't work.

Those characters are not treated in any special way in HTML, they are simply whitespaces. If you want to create a line break in HTML, you have to use the `<br />` tag.

From the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#h-9.1) (emphasis mine):

> This specification does not indicate the behavior, rendering or otherwise, of space characters other than those explicitly identified here as white space characters. **For this reason, authors should use appropriate elements and styles to achieve visual formatting effects that involve white space, rather than space characters.**

---

**To be clear:** This has *nothing* to do with JavaScript, only with how HTML works. Tiny example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ah2J7). I have a line break in my source code (that's the same as what would be created with `document.write('Foo \n bar')`), but the line break is not rendered in by the browser.

If you use `alert` or `console.log` instead of `document.write` you will see the actual generated string, because the string is not displayed in a HTML context.

Comment: so 'when' does the above escape sequences work? If the file was a .js file would they work? I'd like to understand why if possible. Whitespace would be &nbsp; - so you're saying JavaScript ignores them in an HTML page? I thought when I'm coding between <script> tags that it is being interpreted as JavaScript - hence the \' and \\ and \" work fine even though HTML doesn't treat those any special way? Further clarification?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. Of course all those escape sequences "work". If you use `document.write('Foo \n bar')`, then you are inserting a character sequence with a line break into the HTML document. However, you won't be able to **see** the line break, because HTML doesn't recognize it. This has *nothing* to do with JavaScript, only with how HTML works. Tiny example: http://jsfiddle.net/Ah2J7/. I have a line break in my source code (that's the same as what would be created with `document.write('Foo \n bar')`), but the line break is not rendered in by the browser.

Comment: If you use `alert` or `console.log` instead of `document.write` you will see the actual generated string, because the string is not displayed in a HTML context.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you for further explanation!